# Passing state from input to a switch with two arguments in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, frontend

What am I trying to achieve is passing the state from this input:

```
  <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth margin="normal">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="isEbitda">
                          EBITDA
                        </InputLabel>
                        <Select                       
                          inputProps={{
                          name: "isEbitda",
                          id: "isEbitda"}}
                          label="EBITDA"
                          fullWidth
                          value={this.state.isEbitda}
                          onChange={(e) => this.handleisEbitda(e)}
                        >
                          <MenuItem  value={false}>No</MenuItem>
                          <MenuItem  value={true}>Yes</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                      </FormControl>
```

...so I can use it as a second as a second parameter in switch statement in this function:

```
 disableImprovementCalculationCards() {
    this.setState({
      ebitCardDisabled: false,
      ebitPlusCardDisabled: false,
      oviCardDisabled: false,
      EbitdaCardDisabled: false,
      isEbitda: true
    });


    switch (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId, this.state.isEbitda) {
      case "":
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
          EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
          isEbitda: true
        });
        break;
      case "1" && true:
        this.setState({
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
        });
        break;
        case "1" && false:
            this.setState({
              ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
              oviCardDisabled: true,
              EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
            });
            break;
      case "2" && true:
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
        });
        break;
        case "2" && false:
            this.setState({
              ebitCardDisabled: true,
              oviCardDisabled: true,
              EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
            });
            break;
      case "3"  && false || true:
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
        });
        break;
      case "4"  && true:
        this.setState({
          oviCardDisabled: true,
        });
        break;
      case "5"  && true:
        this.setState({
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
        });
        break;
      case "6"  && true:
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
        });
        break;
    }
  }
```

The purpose of a second parameter in the switch statement to case to hide/show an input called EbitdaCard. However, no such thing happens. I am not sure whether I do not pass the state properly, or there is an error in the function I pass it into?

@Michael P. Bazos I have changed switch statement into if else, but the input from isEbitda field still doesn't work:

```
 disableImprovementCalculationCards() {
    this.setState({
      ebitCardDisabled: false,
      ebitPlusCardDisabled: false,
      oviCardDisabled: false,
      EbitdaCardDisabled: false,
      isEbitda: true
    });


    if (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "") {
    
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
          EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
          isEbitda: true
        });
     }
      else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "1" && this.state.isEbitda == true) {
        this.setState({
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "1" && this.state.isEbitda == false) {
        this.setState({
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
          EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
       
    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "2" && this.state.isEbitda == true) {
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }

    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "2" && this.state.isEbitda == false) {
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          oviCardDisabled: true,
          EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
      
    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "3") {
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
          EbitdaCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "4") {
        this.setState({
          oviCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "5") {
        this.setState({
          ebitPlusCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
    else if  (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId == "6") {
        this.setState({
          ebitCardDisabled: true,
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: `switch` is a bad statement for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is there:

```
switch (this.state.CreateProjectCommand.valueImprovementTypeId, this.state.isEbitda) {
    case "":
        // ...
        break;
    case "1" && true:
        // ...
        break;
    case "1" && false:
        // ...
}
```

You cannot use switch...case statements with two expressions as you are doing.

Replace this part with if...else if statements for more flexibility